# Check for different time than start time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datebox

I have the following code that works fine for updating the end time to 30 minutes from now. However I want to check if user changes the end time to less than start time, then update start time to same time or disable the input. The idea is that users can't put an end time prior to start time.

My HTML:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="starttime">Start Time</label>
  <input name="starttime" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="starttime" readonly data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "timeFormat": 12}' />
  <label for="endtime">End Time</label>
  <input name="endtime" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="endtime" readonly data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "timeFormat": 12}' />
</li>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('#starttime').live('change', function() {
    var currentTime=new Date();
    var starttime=sealtime.timeto24HoursFormat($('#starttime').val());

    if(starttime.split(":").length>1){
        currentTime.setHours(starttime.split(":")[0]);
        currentTime.setMinutes(starttime.split(":")[1]);
        currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes()+30);
    }
    var hours=currentTime.getHours().toString();
    if(hours<10)
        hours='0'+hours;
    var minutes=currentTime.getMinutes().toString();
    if(minutes<10)
        minutes='0'+minutes;
    $('#endtime').val(sealtime.timeto12HoursFormat(hours+':'+minutes+":00"));
});
$('#endtime').live('change', function() {
    var currentTime=new Date();
    var endtime=sealtime.timeto24HoursFormat($('#endtime').val());
    var starttime=sealtime.timeto24HoursFormat($('#starttime').val());

    if(endtime.split(":").length>1){
        currentTime.setHours(endtime.split(":")[0]);
        currentTime.setMinutes(endtime.split(":")[1]);
        currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes()-0);
    }
    if (endtime.split(":").length < starttime.split(":").length){
        var hours=currentTime.getHours().toString();
        if(hours<10)
            hours='0'+hours;
        var minutes=currentTime.getMinutes().toString();
        if(minutes<10)
            minutes='0'+minutes;
        $('#starttime').val(sealtime.timeto12HoursFormat(hours+':'+minutes+":00"));

    }
});
```

Comment: check this plugin : http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

Comment: Had no idea that existed. Very cool